# Partition map issues external WD SSD exfat drive, how can I re-add EFI partition?

Tags: terminal, efi, repair, fsck

**Partition map issues external WD SSD exfat drive, how can I re-add EFI partition?**

this week , partial data disappeared on this external drive . Mac's first aid showed that the partition map had issues . error said :

**Couldn't modify partition map (-69874)**

basically the partitions are healthy (i've used four softwares to analyze this hard drive, all three softwares except Mac First Aid act like the drive is perfect and unharmed) but the parent device wont successfully run first aid and thats the error . Mac First Aid treats the two partitions 1 and 2 as if they're healthy , but the parent device is triggering an alert ...

so ive been trying to repair it and haven't been able to . its a MBR EXFAT .

so , i converted it to GPT EXFAT to better suit my mac .

now im getting this error :

**Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
This disk doesn't contain an EFI system partition. If you want to start up your computer with this disk or include it in a RAID set, back up your data and partition this disk. :(-69767)
Operation failed...**

??? what on earth ... ?

so i guess the external drive doesn't have an EFI and that's been the problem all along ?

what i have is a very healthy drive , no hardware damage , no possible indicator it could've been damaged ... yet data is missing as of this week when my computer froze and the external drive had trouble mounting .

its a really high quality drive that i use on nice computers , new cables , even power surge protector , and my data is basic day-to day stuff .

how can i place an EFI partition on this external hard drive again ? thanks

Comment: It shouldn't need an EFI partition. Macs can't boot from ExFAT anyway. I think you found one error caused by a write error & have now compounded it by trying to convert the underlying format. If you have a backup, now would be the time to just nuke & pave the drive.